# java: how to get the result of a URL query

Tags: java

```
       URL aURL = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/");

    System.out.println("protocol = " + aURL.getProtocol());
    System.out.println("authority = " + aURL.getAuthority());
    System.out.println("host = " + aURL.getHost());
    System.out.println("port = " + aURL.getPort());
    System.out.println("path = " + aURL.getPath());
    System.out.println("query = " + aURL.getQuery());
    System.out.println("filename = " + aURL.getFile());
    System.out.println("ref = " + aURL.getRef());
```

The code above shows some properties of URL, however what i need to know is if there is a way to get the result of a query executed in URL, i have a website for testing purposes and i am making db queries through the url (mostly SELECTs) and displaying the result in the webpage's html, i was wondering if there is already a function that gets the result of that specific SELECT, so far i made a method to download the html of the page to a .txt, sort the content and then get the result of the query, however it is not very practical.
-Regards

Comment: Are you asking how to make an http request?

Comment: ...or are you asking how to directly query the SQL database in your code (see [JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) )

Comment: idealy, i want to get the sql query result to a string through url

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a simple get does the job.
Source: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

```
    private void sendGet() throws Exception {

    String url = "your url here";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println(response.toString());

}
```